Complex Potential Between Axes and a Hyperbola
I'm looking at the exact same question as here:
Complex potential between axes & hyperbola
(Advanced Engineering Mathematics 8th edition, Erwin Kreyszig, problem 12 of section 16.1)
Find the potential in the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane between the axes and the hyperbola $xy=1$.
I had surmised that the following would be the solution:
$$
\Phi(x,y)=Axy+B
$$
It seems reasonable, it meets the Laplace equation criteria - is this sufficient?  This isn't the only equation that meets the Laplace equation.  There may be no other solution that meets the geometry, but I'm not sure how to prove that.

Did you notice in the solution to the other thread, they went on past that point and found a holomorphic function? The problem is, $\Phi$ is a real potential, not a complex potential (apparently needing to be a holomorphic function - I don't have access to the book, so I cannot look this up). So if your purpose is to produce a complex potential, $\Phi$ does not cut it.

Once I have the real portion, I would use Cauchy-Reimann theorem of an analytic function (as well as the boundary conditions) to determine the complex portion.  You're right, that the real portion does not complete the question, but that's not where I'm stuck.

Not every function used as the "real portion" has a  counterpart that can serve as the imaginary portion such that the two satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. The function has to be harmonic. But why are you stuck, when the answer in the other thread already points out the solution?

I'd just assumed the equipotential lines are xy=a with 0<a<1.  Seems reasonable, especially as the boundaries are xy=0 and xy=1.  And yes, it meets the Laplace condition.  But am I missing some rigor here?  Is there another equation that meets these conditions?  I can't come up with anything, but I haven't tried every possible equation.  Maybe I should see if I can find a general solution to Laplace?
